# How to catch stream management handled stanza value

Tags: xmpp, smack, asmack, stream-management

Hi guys i am developing chatting application using xmpp smack

in that i am using stream management when i send message i got like this from server

```
SENT (0): <message id='sqn7K-7' to='user4@mobizz.com' type='chat'><body>fdf</body></message>

RCV (0): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='1'/>(need to catch this h value)
```

i need to catch that **acknowledgement** for showing single tick mark like whatsapp

for that i am using below link
http://linyu19872008.iteye.com/blog/1845543

but its not working

i am struck here can any one suggest me

Thanks in adavance

naresh

Answer (score 1):

You don't need that value when using Smack 4.1. Use the StanzaAcknowleged listeners.

Comment: https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/4.1.0/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/tcp/XMPPTCPConnection.html#addStanzaAcknowledgedListener(org.jivesoftware.smack.StanzaListener)

Comment: we are implemented StanzaAcknowleged listeners. we need to get h(handledcount) from server.    We are getting 3 types of messages 1.IQ 2.Presence 3. Message but h value is not any of these types.so, we are not able to catch stream management response from server. can you please let us know how to catch this sm response (<a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='1'/>)  this we are using for single tick mark like whatsApp which indicates that message has been delivered to server. we are using ejabbard server. and smack 4.2.0